# Роутер работает некорректно

Tags: php, mvc

прописал в роутере строчку, по которой он должен вызывать контроллер и его методы, но это не работает, что я делаю не так?

```
<?php

namespace app;

use app\controllers\auth\AuthController;
use app\controllers\home\HomeController;
use app\controllers\pages\PagesController;
use app\controllers\roles\RolesController;
use app\controllers\users\UsersController;
use app\controllers\todo\tasks\ToDoTasksController;

class Router
{

    private $routes = [
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/?$/' => ['controller' => 'home\\HomeController', 'action' => 'index'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/users(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'users\\UsersController'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/auth(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'auth\\AuthController'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/roles(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'roles\\RolesController'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/pages(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'pages\\PagesController'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/todo\/categories(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'todo\\categories\\ToDoCategoriesController'],
        '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/todo\/tasks(\/(?P<action>[a-z]+)(\/(?P<id>\d+))?)?$/' => ['controller' => 'todo\\tasks\\ToDoTasksController'],
       ==> Вот она '/^\/' . APP_BASE_PATH . '\/todo\/tasks\/tag(\/(?P<id>\d+))?$/' => ['controller' => 'todo\\tasks\\ToDoTasksController', 'action' => 'tasksByTag'], <== Вот она
    ];

    public function run()
    {

        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $controller = null;
        $action = null;
        $params = null;

        foreach ($this->routes as $pattern => $route) {

            if (preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches)) {

                $controller = 'app\\controllers\\' . $route['controller'];
                $action = $route['action'] ?? $matches['action'] ?? 'index';
                $params = array_filter($matches, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
                break;

            }

        }

        if (!$controller) {
            http_response_code(404);
            echo 'Страница не найдена';
            return;
        }

        $controllerInstance = new $controller();

        if (!method_exists($controllerInstance, $action)) {
            http_response_code(404);
            echo 'Страница не найдена';
            return;
        }

        call_user_func_array([$controllerInstance, $action], [$params]);

    }

}
```

А вот что я получаю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Включи отладку, пройдись по коду отладчиком, посмотри что не так

Comment: какой читаемый роутинг.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не работает xdebug, хотя раньше все в порядке было... Просто страница висит, грузится и ничего не происходит, но $_SERVER например все таки в дебаге отображается

Comment: Всё, заработал роутер) Спасибо)

Comment: Просто интереса ради - в чём ошибка была?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Без понятия, просто пришлось делать как у автора by-tag вместо tag, я пока в регулярках не силен, скорее всего регулярка по другому чуть должна выглядеть :/